# 'metadatalock' occured when I did 'lock tables [table_name] write'

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking, mariadb

I did it like below

```
-- connection 1
START TRANSACTION;
LOCK TABLES [table_name] WRITE;

-- connection 2
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM [table_name]; -- waiting for table metadata lock
```

I don't understand above situation.
I thought WRITE LOCK doesn't prevent SELECT query.

When I did like below,

```
-- connection 1
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE [table_name] SET [column = value] WHERE id = 1;

-- connection 2
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM [table_name] WHERE id = 1; -- doesn't wait
```

SELECT doesn't wait as you saw.
And I thought WRITE LOCK also work like UPDATE clause.
But it seems like not..

Now I know something wrong?

Comment: Have you look in the output from **SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;** There you can find more details

Comment: In general, `LOCK TABLES` should not be used with InnoDB.  Why are you using it?

Comment: I was just studying about MySQL Lock. I won't plan to use this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write lock does not work like row-level locking.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html says:

> `WRITE` lock:
>
> - Only the session that holds the lock can access the table. No other session can access it until the lock is released.

"Access" in this context means read or write.